# How can you test if a player is holding an item with a specific name in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I don't know how to test if a player is holding an item with a specific name, but I know it's something like 
`/testfor @e[type=Player,SelectedItem=example_id,Slot=0]`, but I probably got it totally wrong... Can you guys help?

Answer (score 2):

A list of valid target selector parameters can be found [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Target_selector_arguments).

`/testfor` syntax:

```
/testfor <selector> {dataTags}
```

You'll be checking the player's NBT data instead. The `SelectedItem` compound holds a copy of the player's currently-held item, minus the `Slot` tag:

```
/testfor @e[type=Player] {SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:stone",tag:{display:{Name:"Custom Name"}}}}
```

Or if you need to target the matching player afterwards, you'll assign a score.

Objective prerequisite:

```
/scoreboard objectives add HoldingItem dummy
```

Detection:

```
/scoreboard players set @e[type=Player,score_HoldingItem_min=1] HoldingItem 0
/scoreboard players set @e[type=Player] HoldingItem 1 {SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:stone",tag:{display:{Name:"Custom Name"}}}}
/say @a[score_HoldingItem_min=1]
```

Comment: You might note that SelectedItem was added in the 1.9 snapshots.

Comment: @Hurricane996 That is incorrect. It was added during the 1.8 snapshots.